# sql select all children AND grandchildren from a certain ancestor (root category)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've got some images in several categories. All categories are in a certain table (let's say tbl_categories). The level of subcategories is between 1 and 10. 
I would like to create a query that gives all id's of subcategories (and their subcategories, and so on ...) from a certain root category (which can be a subcategory itself).

Example:

```
 Category 1
    subcategory a
 Category 2
    subcategory b
        subsubcategory I
        subsubcategory II
    subcategory c
```

If i use category 2, i want subcategories b and c, and subsubcategories I en II as a result.
Sounds fairly easy but i haven't got a clue.

I'm fairly new to writing queries...

Thanks

Comment: Can you show your actual table structure?

Comment: And also which RDBMS (MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, etc.) you are using?

Comment: I've got a tbl_mm_cat which has a uid_local (refers to the id's of the images in tbl_img) and a uid_foreign (refers to the id's of the categories in tbl_cat).

Euh i'm using a CMS and it has a phpMyAdmin module in the backend...
I successfully used this to check which images are in categories 2 or 4:       
$sql = mysql_query ("SELECT uid_local FROM `tbl_mm_cat` WHERE uid_foreign IN(2,4) AND uid_local ='".$item->getId()."'")or die(mysql_error());

the getId() simply gets every id of every image
(it's a search module, and users can only search in certain categories)

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:**

```
//Parents
$data = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("select id,name from categories where parent = 0"));

//Childrens
foreach( $data as $key => $row)
{
    $data[$key]['childrens'] = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("select id,name from categories where parent ='".mysql_real_escape_string( $row['id'] )."'"));

    //childrens
    foreach( $data[$key]['childrens'] as $_key => $_row )
    {
        $data[$key]['childrens'][$_key]['childrens'] = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("select id,name from categories where parent ='".mysql_real_escape_string( $_row['id'] )."'"));
    }
}

    //Print Array
print_r( $data );
```